# Syntax highlighting: what is the difference between :syntax match and :match?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, syntax-highlighting

Simple question -- what is the difference between the two? When I try, for example, to highlight characters on every line after the 80th with `highlight link OverLength Error` (OverLength being an arbitrary syntax name), using

```
match OverLength /\%80v.\+/
```

highlights the characters as desired, but

```
syntax match OverLength /\%80v.\+/
```

does not. What's going on here? Is use of the syntax sub-commands restricted to files in the `.vim/syntax` folder? What would even be the rationale for that?

Comment: I think you mean `match OverLength /\%80v.\+/` and `:hi OverLength Error` And the difference is that `:syn ` commands are used for actually defining the syntax of a buffer (and they basically can build a language) by matching against different parts of a buffer, while `:match and getmatch()` function allows for easier more "throw away like" highlighting that can easily added and changed without having to need to build up a complete syntax language. syntax highlighting can get really complex really fast, because of the priorities in which parts are defined

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks for the help; edited my question per your corrections. If you post this below I think it would be an appropriate "accepted answer".